# When can I call base class method using self in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I read all kinds of `super` usage for inheritance in Python. But I also get the following code work in Python 2.7.5

```
class A:
    def f3(self):
        print('a f3')

class B(A):
    def f1(self):
        self.f3()

b = B()
b.f1() # 'a f3'
```

Is this actually correct in production? Can we use `self` instead of `super(...)`?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need super since you are not overriding a superclass method, did you intend your functions to be both called f1, maybe?

Comment: in python 2, `class A:` should really be `class A(object):`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque This is probably just Python3

Comment: This is clearly not a good duplicate since OP is not calling the same method.

Comment: It says python 2 in the question @OlivierMelançon

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, why do you think the marked dupe is not right.  It appears the OP is confused about the use of `super()`.

Comment: @StephenRauch Because the duplicate is about the difference between super().f and self.f, here it is not even the same method